# Keep the video chat app running when the home button is clicked

Tags: android

I am currently developing a video chat application, it is working fine no problem at all, my issue is that the video and audio streams cut when I click on the home button and continues as I come back, this means that the other peer sees my video Container freezing, until I get the app again from the background, hoping that the system did not kill the app if the resources of the device is not enough. What I want to do is something like what I see in the Messenger application (the one related to Facebook), so when the user clicks on the home screen a dialog activity comes up containing the video or some text notifying that there is a call running, to prevent the app from stop sending video and audio streams.

UPDATE:
I need to make a UI accessor for the application when it is in the background

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521307/starting-a-view-from-a-service

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture

Comment: I can't use this solution @mudit_sen because the application is made to support api 24 and up, I wish I can use it, it is exactly what I am looking for :(

Comment: @mudit_sen there is a great difference between what I need and what is in here in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521307/starting-a-view-from-a-service while the app is in the foreground, or am I missing something
the issue is that I want to completely put the application on the background and I can't override the home button click to launch a small dialogActivity to keep my app live, in the thread he is asking about putting two activities on top of each other.

Comment: @mudit_sen it seems that u have experienced this issue before :) thanks for help anyway

Comment: What you need view that can be shown after an activity is closed. So you can create a service and create your view there. That's how facebook does it. Messenger bubble is a service running until you close it pushing the bubble to cross icon. But after Oreo android released picture in picture view which is quite easy to use.

Comment: not the head-chat, I mean the video chat, when u r in a call and click home, a small square  dialog will appeare

Comment: It is upon you which view you want to show in your service. Facebook messenger is showing a chat bubble. You can show your chat view. You won't find any step by step solution for this on StackOverflow.

Comment: thanks @mudit_sen you really helped